How can I solve T(n) = 5T(√n) + (logn)^6 using recurrence tree?
I know how to use recurrence tree method but in this example it has log in it how should I solve this?
T(n) = 5T(√n) + (logn)^6
(Logn)^6 is causing problems should I solve this like a normal logn?can someone please explain this to me step by step?
